# Hide list on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I have a list showing up when I click on button, the problem is that I want to hide the list whenever it loses focus i.e. user clicks anywhere on a page, but not on that list. How can I do this? Also, you can see how it should look at last.fm, where's list of profile settings (`li.profileItem`).
(`ul.del li ul` by default is `display:none`)
Basic list structure:

```
<ul class='del'>
    <li>
        <button class='deletePage'></button>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My function for displaying this list:

```
$(".deletePage").click(function(){
    if( $(this).siblings(0).css("display") == "block" ){
        $(this).siblings(0).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(0).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

You can bind a `click` handler to the `document` to hide the list, then attach a separate handler to the button which calls [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
$(document).click(function() {
 $('.list-to-hide').hide();
});

$('.show-list-button').click(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Alternatively, you could use the [jQuery outside events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/):

```
$('.show-list-button').bind('clickoutside', function() {
 $('.list-to-hide').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ben Alman's "Outside Events" plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) which adds the ability to `bind('clickoutside')` to handle things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document click event. If the user clicks inside the div the event propagation stops there (e.stopPropagation) else it will be handled by the document click event which checks if the menu is open and if it is closes it.

```
$(document).click(function() { 
  // check if the menu is open, if so close it
});

$("#windowdiv").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do stuff
});
```